# JTable with merged column headers

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm working developing a system and I need to create a special table take a look:

[image]

Row headers and column titles are always static.

Is it possible to create that kind of table with Netbeans?

Comment: Yes it can be done, no it can't be done with the form editor - you're going to have to get your hands dirty.  You can check out [this example](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the [link](http://www.esus.com/docs/GetQuestionPage.jsp?uid=1272) about how to add `Nested Table Header`.