# how to combine two column headers in jtable in swings

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to make a gui like this in swing can u help me ..  is there any way to combine column headers by columns and rows

[image]

Comment: Check this,  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852886/jtable-with-merged-column-headers)

Comment: Always, always, ALWAYS search Stack Overflow, Google, etc. for the answer to your question before you ask it. There's a good chance that someone somewhere in the world at some time wanted the same thing as you.

Comment: This is a very common question, and very, very hard to implement well.  You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201590/can-jtableheader-span-over-multiple-columns/13202610#13202610) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206578/show-column-header-on-dragging-column/20208995#20208995) for examples...

Comment: This question is asked quite often. And solutions were partial: fixed columns or only basic look and feel, or 2 rows only, or a commercial license. Today there exists a free solution with L&F support, ability to move columns and arbitrary number of rows. I'll leave a link for future searchers to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31496799/4540645).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want multi header row jtable. You have to Group your header.

GroupableHeaderExample.java

```
public class GroupableHeaderExample extends JFrame {

  GroupableHeaderExample() {
    super( "Groupable Header Example" );

    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dm.setDataVector(new Object[][]{
      {"119","foo","bar","ja","ko","zh"},
      {"911","bar","foo","en","fr","pt"}},
    new Object[]{"SNo.","1","2","Native","2","3"});

    JTable table = new JTable( dm ) {
      protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
          return new GroupableTableHeader(columnModel);
      }
    };


    TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();
    ColumnGroup g_name = new ColumnGroup("Name");
    g_name.add(cm.getColumn(1));
    g_name.add(cm.getColumn(2));
    ColumnGroup g_lang = new ColumnGroup("Language");
    g_lang.add(cm.getColumn(3));
    ColumnGroup g_other = new ColumnGroup("Others");
    g_other.add(cm.getColumn(4));
    g_other.add(cm.getColumn(5));
    g_lang.add(g_other);

    GroupableTableHeader header = (GroupableTableHeader)table.getTableHeader();
    header.addColumnGroup(g_name);
    header.addColumnGroup(g_lang);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( table );
    getContentPane().add( scroll );
    setSize( 400, 120 );   
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GroupableHeaderExample frame = new GroupableHeaderExample();
    frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) {
  System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

ColumnGroup.java

```
public class ColumnGroup {

    protected TableCellRenderer renderer;

    protected List<TableColumn> columns;
    protected List<ColumnGroup> groups;

    protected String text;
    protected int margin = 0;

    public ColumnGroup(String text) {
        this(text, null);
    }

    public ColumnGroup(String text, TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        this.text = text;
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.columns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>();
        this.groups = new ArrayList<ColumnGroup>();
    }

    public void add(TableColumn column) {
        columns.add(column);
    }

    public void add(ColumnGroup group) {
        groups.add(group);
    }

    /**
     * @param column
     *            TableColumn
     */
    public List<ColumnGroup> getColumnGroups(TableColumn column) {
        if (!contains(column)) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<ColumnGroup> result = new ArrayList<ColumnGroup>();
        result.add(this);
        if (columns.contains(column)) {
            return result;
        }
        for (ColumnGroup columnGroup : groups) {
            result.addAll(columnGroup.getColumnGroups(column));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean contains(TableColumn column) {
        if (columns.contains(column)) {
            return true;
        }
        for (ColumnGroup group : groups) {
            if (group.contains(column)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public TableCellRenderer getHeaderRenderer() {
        return renderer;
    }

    public void setHeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    public String getHeaderValue() {
        return text;
    }

    public Dimension getSize(JTable table) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = this.renderer;
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }
        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, getHeaderValue() == null || getHeaderValue().trim().isEmpty() ? " "
                : getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, -1);
        int height = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
        int width = 0;
        for (ColumnGroup columnGroup : groups) {
            width += columnGroup.getSize(table).width;
        }
        for (TableColumn tableColumn : columns) {
            width += tableColumn.getWidth();
            width += margin;
        }
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public void setColumnMargin(int margin) {
        this.margin = margin;
        for (ColumnGroup columnGroup : groups) {
            columnGroup.setColumnMargin(margin);
        }
    }

}
```

GroupableTableHeader.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GroupableTableHeader extends JTableHeader {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String uiClassID = "GroupableTableHeaderUI";

    protected List<ColumnGroup> columnGroups = new ArrayList<ColumnGroup>();

    public GroupableTableHeader(TableColumnModel model) {
        super(model);
        setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
        setReorderingAllowed(false);
        // setDefaultRenderer(new MultiLineHeaderRenderer());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUI() {
        setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void setReorderingAllowed(boolean b) {
        super.setReorderingAllowed(false);
    }

    public void addColumnGroup(ColumnGroup g) {
        columnGroups.add(g);
    }

    public List<ColumnGroup> getColumnGroups(TableColumn col) {
        for (ColumnGroup group : columnGroups) {
            List<ColumnGroup> groups = group.getColumnGroups(col);
            if (!groups.isEmpty()) {
                return groups;
            }
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public void setColumnMargin() {
        int columnMargin = getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();
        for (ColumnGroup group : columnGroups) {
            group.setColumnMargin(columnMargin);
        }
    }

}
```

GroupableTableHeaderUI.java

```
public class GroupableTableHeaderUI extends BasicTableHeaderUI {

    protected GroupableTableHeader getHeader() {
        return (GroupableTableHeader) header;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
        if (header.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        int column = 0;
        Dimension size = header.getSize();
        Rectangle cellRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        Map<ColumnGroup, Rectangle> groupSizeMap = new HashMap<ColumnGroup, Rectangle>();

        for (Enumeration<TableColumn> enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();) {
            cellRect.height = size.height;
            cellRect.y = 0;
            TableColumn aColumn = enumeration.nextElement();
            List<ColumnGroup> groups = getHeader().getColumnGroups(aColumn);
            int groupHeight = 0;
            for (ColumnGroup group : groups) {
                Rectangle groupRect = groupSizeMap.get(group);
                if (groupRect == null) {
                    groupRect = new Rectangle(cellRect);
                    Dimension d = group.getSize(header.getTable());
                    groupRect.width = d.width;
                    groupRect.height = d.height;
                    groupSizeMap.put(group, groupRect);
                }
                paintCell(g, groupRect, group);
                groupHeight += groupRect.height;
                cellRect.height = size.height - groupHeight;
                cellRect.y = groupHeight;
            }
            cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth();
            if (cellRect.intersects(clipBounds)) {
                paintCell(g, cellRect, column);
            }
            cellRect.x += cellRect.width;
            column++;
        }
    }

    private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, int columnIndex) {
        TableColumn aColumn = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex);
        TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = getHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }
        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false, false,
                -1, columnIndex);

        c.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));

        rendererPane.paintComponent(g, c, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y, cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
    }

    private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, ColumnGroup cGroup) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = cGroup.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = getHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }

        Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(header.getTable(), cGroup.getHeaderValue(), false,
                false, -1, -1);
        rendererPane
                .paintComponent(g, component, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y, cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
    }

    private int getHeaderHeight() {
        int headerHeight = 0;
        TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
        for (int column = 0; column < columnModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            TableColumn aColumn = columnModel.getColumn(column);
            TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
            if (renderer == null) {
                renderer = getHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
            }

            Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false,
                    false, -1, column);
            int cHeight = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
            List<ColumnGroup> groups = getHeader().getColumnGroups(aColumn);
            for (ColumnGroup group : groups) {
                cHeight += group.getSize(header.getTable()).height;
            }
            headerHeight = Math.max(headerHeight, cHeight);
        }
        return headerHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        int width = 0;
        for (Enumeration<TableColumn> enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();) {
            TableColumn aColumn = enumeration.nextElement();
            width += aColumn.getPreferredWidth();
        }
        return createHeaderSize(width);
    }

    private Dimension createHeaderSize(int width) {
        TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
        width += columnModel.getColumnMargin() * columnModel.getColumnCount();
        if (width > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            width = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        return new Dimension(width, getHeaderHeight());
    }

}
```

You can find this at [Groupable(Group) Header Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GroupableGroupHeaderExample.htm).

Comment: Which has being linked 3 times, which breaks the default row sorting and column dragging support of a regular `JTable` not to mention the default look and feel of the row headers. You may also wish to look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [`JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) - Nit pick I know, for which I applogise, but there it is...

Comment: can you please tell me how to add ColumnGroup with button?

Comment: The solution, which is from 1998, is also extremely slow for very large tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Perfectly Working Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


/**
    Example of a table header that allows cells to span multiple columns.

    Copyright (C) 2001 Christian Kaufhold <ch-ka...@gmx.de>

    This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
    modify it under the terms of the GNU Library General Public
    License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
    version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

    This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
    Library General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU Library General Public
    License along with this library; if not, write to the Free
    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

/** Just a default renderer. To work with TableHeader, the corresponding
    TableHeader must be read from the JTable client property (see code),
    since JTable.getTableHeader() cannot be used.
*/
class DefaultHeaderRenderer
    extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    {
        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
    }

    public void updateUI()
    {
        super.updateUI();

        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);

        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
    }


    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
        (JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused,
        int row, int column)
    {
        TableHeader header;

        if (table != null && (header = (TableHeader)table.getClientProperty(TableHeader.KEY)) != null)
        {
            setForeground(header.getForeground());
            setBackground(header.getBackground());

            setFont(header.getFont());

            setComponentOrientation(header.getComponentOrientation());

            setEnabled(header.isEnabled());
        }
        else
        {
            setForeground(UIManager.getColor("TableHeader.foreground"));
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TableHeader.background"));

            setFont(UIManager.getFont("TableHeader.font"));

            setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.UNKNOWN);

            setEnabled(true);
        }

        setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "");

        return this;
    }
}

/** An alternative TableHeader that allows header cells to span multiple
    columns. This is just a bare-bones prototype, things to do are:
    - Optimize paint code to paint only concerned columns
    - Area conversion (columnAtPoint, headerRect or similar)
    - getToolTipText(MouseEvent)
    - resizing of columns (which of the columns should be resized?)
    - moving of columns (which cannot be done in real time since JTable
      doesn't know that it has to paint multiple dragged columns.)
    - how to serialize if the renderer isn't serializable?
    - Accessibility

    Note: JTable aggressively installs its JTableHeader in the column header
    view of JScrollPane, even if it is set to 'null'. To avoid confusion,
    override its configureEnclosingScrollPane() method to do nothing, for
    example.

    Typically, a TableHeader is set up like this:

    TableColumnModel columns = ...;

    // columns contains some XTableColumns that have spans set.

    JTable table = new FixedJTable(data, columns); // see above which fix

    table.setTableHeader(null);

    TableHeader header = new TableHeader(table);

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

    pane.setColumnHeaderView(header);
*/

public class TableHeader
    extends JComponent
{
    /** TableColumn that also has a headerSpan property. */
    public static class XTableColumn
        extends TableColumn
    {
        private int headerSpan;


        public XTableColumn()
        {
            headerSpan = 1;
        }

        /** number of columns that the header cell spans. */
        public final int headerSpan()
        {
            return headerSpan;
        }

        /** set 'headerSpan'. requires newHeaderSpan > 0. During the
            manipulation of TableColumnModels, there may be times where
            a column spans more columns than there are at the right of it.
            This state is only allowed during such modifications. Once they
            are finished, all spans must not be too large. 
            XTableColumns that are hidden by the spans of their predecessors
            are ignored (in the TableHeader, of course not by the JTable).

            Due to the broken notification way of TableColumnModel/Table-
            Column there is no way to notify the header that it must 
            repaint().
            If firePropertyChange were not private, we could send the
            following fake event
            firePropertyChange("width", getWidth(), getWidth());
            which would handle that (only width and preferred width
            changes can reach the header).
            The moral is: don't change spans later, or if, repaint the
            header manually.
        */
        public void setHeaderSpan(int newHeaderSpan)
        {
            headerSpan = newHeaderSpan;   
        }
    }


    private static TableCellRenderer staticDefaultRenderer
        = new DefaultHeaderRenderer();

    /** Under this key, the table header is stored in the JTable, so that
        the renderer can access it. See demo renderer above.
    */
    public static Object KEY = TableHeader.class;

    private JTable table;

    private transient TableColumnModel columns;

    private TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer
        = staticDefaultRenderer;


    private transient Listener listener;


   public TableHeader(JTable table)
    {
        this.table = table;

        table.putClientProperty(KEY, this);

        this.columns = table.getColumnModel();

        this.listener = createListener();

        table.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);

        columns.addColumnModelListener(listener);

        add(new CellRendererPane());

        updateUI();
    }


    public void updateUI()
    {
        LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont
            (this, "TableHeader.background", "TableHeader.foreground",
            "TableHeader.font");

        LookAndFeel.installBorder(this, "TableHeader.border");

        if (defaultRenderer instanceof JComponent)
            ((JComponent)defaultRenderer).updateUI();

        revalidate(); repaint();
    }


    public final JTable table()
    {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(JTable t)
    {
        JTable oldTable = table;
        TableColumnModel oldColumns = columns;

        table.putClientProperty(KEY, null);

        table.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);

        columns.removeColumnModelListener(listener);

        table = t;

        table.putClientProperty(KEY, this);

        columns = t.getColumnModel();

        table.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);

        columns.addColumnModelListener(listener);

        revalidate(); repaint();

        firePropertyChange("table", oldTable, table);
        firePropertyChange("columns", oldColumns, columns);
    }

    public final TableColumnModel columns()
    {
        return columns;
    }

    /** For serialization, the TableCellRenderer is needed to be serializable.
     */
    public void setDefaultRenderer(TableCellRenderer r)
    {
        TableCellRenderer oldRenderer = defaultRenderer;

        defaultRenderer = r;

        revalidate(); repaint();

        firePropertyChange("defaultRenderer", oldRenderer, defaultRenderer);
    }

    public final TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer()
    {
        return defaultRenderer;
    }


    private TableCellRenderer renderer(TableColumn c)
    {
        TableCellRenderer result = c.getHeaderRenderer();

        if (result != null)
            return result;

        return defaultRenderer;
    }


    private Component component(TableCellRenderer r, TableColumn c, int column)
    {
        return r.getTableCellRendererComponent
            (table, c.getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, column);
    }


    private Dimension size(long innerWidth)
    {
        Insets i = getInsets();

        return new Dimension((int)Math.min(innerWidth + i.left + i.bottom, Integer.MAX_VALUE), innerHeight() + i.top + i.bottom);
    }


    /** Alas, this cannot be cached. */
    private int innerHeight()
    {
        int result = 0;

        int count = columns.getColumnCount();

        for (int j = 0; j < count; )
        {
            TableColumn c = columns.getColumn(j);

            int span;

            if (c instanceof XTableColumn)
                span = ((XTableColumn)c).headerSpan();
            else
                span = 1;

            Component d = component(renderer(c), c, j);

            result = Math.max(result, d.getPreferredSize().height);

            j += span;
        }

        return result;
    }



    public Dimension getMinimumSize()
    {
        if (isMinimumSizeSet())
            return super.getMinimumSize();

        return size(minWidth(columns));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet())
            return super.getPreferredSize();

        return size(preferredWidth(columns));
    }

    public Dimension getMaximumSize()
    {
        if (isMaximumSizeSet())
            return super.getMaximumSize();

        return size(maxWidth(columns));
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Insets i = getInsets();

        Rectangle clip = g.getClipBounds();

        CellRendererPane pane = (CellRendererPane)getComponent(0);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

        r.x = i.left;
        r.y = i.top;
        r.height = getHeight() - i.top - i.bottom;

        if (r.height <= 0)
            return;


        int count = columns.getColumnCount();

        for (int j = 0; j < count; )
        {
            TableColumn c = columns.getColumn(j);

            r.width = c.getWidth();

            int span;

            if (c instanceof XTableColumn)
            {
                span = ((XTableColumn)c).headerSpan();

                if (j + span > count)
                {
                    System.err.println("column: "+j+" span: "+span+" > "+count);
                    System.err.println("This state of TableColumnModel is forbidden!");
                    span = count - j;
                }

                for (int k = 1; k < span; k++)
                    r.width += columns.getColumn(j + k).getWidth();
            }
            else
            {
                span = 1;
            }

            Component d = component(renderer(c), c, j);

            pane.paintComponent(g, d, this, 
                r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height, true);

            r.x += r.width;

            j += span;
        }

        pane.removeAll();
    }


    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        in.defaultReadObject();

        listener = createListener();

        table.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);

        columns = table.getColumnModel();

        columns.addColumnModelListener(listener);
    }


    protected Object clone()
        throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }


    private Listener createListener()
    {
        return new Listener();
    }


    private class Listener
        implements TableColumnModelListener, PropertyChangeListener
    {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getPropertyName().equals("columnModel"))
            {
                TableColumnModel oldColumns = columns;

                columns.removeColumnModelListener(this);

                columns = table.getColumnModel();

                columns.addColumnModelListener(this);

                revalidate(); repaint();

                firePropertyChange("columns", oldColumns, columns);
            }
        }


        public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e)
        {
            revalidate(); repaint();
        }

        public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e)
        {
            revalidate(); repaint();
        }

        public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
        }

        public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e)
        {
            repaint();
        }

        public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
            revalidate(); repaint();
        }
    }  

    /* Utility methods. Copied here from TableColumnModels. */

    public static long minWidth(TableColumnModel columns)
    {
        long result = 0;

        for (Enumeration e = columns.getColumns(); e.hasMoreElements();)
            result += ((TableColumn)e.nextElement()).getMinWidth();

        return result;
    }

    public static long preferredWidth(TableColumnModel columns)
    {
        long result = 0;

        for (Enumeration e = columns.getColumns(); e.hasMoreElements();)
            result += ((TableColumn)e.nextElement()).getPreferredWidth();

        return result;
    }

    public static long maxWidth(TableColumnModel columns)
    {
        long result = 0;

        for (Enumeration e = columns.getColumns(); e.hasMoreElements();)
            result += ((TableColumn)e.nextElement()).getMaxWidth();

        return result;
    }
}


class TableHeaderExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DefaultTableModel data = new DefaultTableModel(10, 0);

        data.addColumn("ABC");
        data.addColumn("DEF");
        data.addColumn("GHI");
        data.addColumn("JKL");
        data.addColumn("MNO");
        data.addColumn("PQR");

        TableColumnModel columns = new DefaultTableColumnModel();

        TableHeader.XTableColumn abc = new TableHeader.XTableColumn();
        abc.setHeaderValue("ABC");
        abc.setHeaderSpan(2);

        TableColumn ghi = new TableColumn(2);
        ghi.setHeaderValue("GHI");

        TableHeader.XTableColumn jkl = new TableHeader.XTableColumn();
        jkl.setHeaderValue("JKL");
        jkl.setHeaderSpan(3);
        jkl.setModelIndex(3);

        columns.addColumn(abc);
        columns.addColumn(new TableColumn(1));
        columns.addColumn(ghi);
        columns.addColumn(jkl);
        columns.addColumn(new TableColumn(4));
        columns.addColumn(new TableColumn(5));

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns)
        {
            protected void configureEnclosingScrollPane()
            {
            }
        };

        table.setTableHeader(null);

        TableHeader header = new TableHeader(table);

        header.setForeground(Color.blue);
        header.setFont(header.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

        pane.setColumnHeaderView(header);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setContentPane(pane);

        f.pack();

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```