# Groupable table header with filter below header

Tags: java, jtable, jtableheader

**Problem**

I'd like to create a groupable table header with a filter row below the header.

I guess the straightforward approach would be to include the filter components in the header. The problem is that the components aren't editable.

I searched, but didn't find a good or working approach. The best and working solution I found so far regarding filter components was putting them outside of the table. But when you have a grouped table that just looks and feels ugly. They must be below the header. Putting the filter components in the footer isn't an option either.

I used the groupable table header code form [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347647/how-to-combine-two-column-headers-in-jtable-in-swings) and added a filter component.

The problem is now that when I click on the components, I can't access them. Instead the row sorting is triggered. Even adding a mouse listener to the textfield doesn't help.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to make the textfields in the table header editable? Or does anyone have a better approach about placing a table filter below the table header?

**Code**

The code so far:

FilterHeader.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FilterHeader extends JPanel {

    public FilterHeader( JTable table, Object value, int columnIndex) {

        setLayout( new BorderLayout());

        // header 
        JLabel header = new JLabel();
        header.setForeground(table.getTableHeader().getForeground());
        header.setBackground(table.getTableHeader().getBackground());
        header.setFont(table.getTableHeader().getFont());

        header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        header.setText(value.toString());
        header.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));

        add( header, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // append filter components to header
        if( columnIndex == 3) {

            JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
            cb.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            cb.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
            cb.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
            cb.setForeground(table.getTableHeader().getForeground());
            cb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,table.getRowHeight() + 4));

            add( cb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        } else {

            JTextField tf = new JTextField( "enter filtertext");
            tf.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            tf.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
            tf.setForeground(table.getTableHeader().getForeground());
            tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            add( tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            tf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                 @Override
                 public void  mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                     System.out.println("textfield clicked"); // doesn't work
                 }
             });
        }


    }

}
```

ColumnGroup.java

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class ColumnGroup {

    protected TableCellRenderer renderer;

    protected List<TableColumn> columns;
    protected List<ColumnGroup> groups;

    protected String text;
    protected int margin = 0;

    public ColumnGroup(String text) {
        this(text, null);
    }

    public ColumnGroup(String text, TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        this.text = text;
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.columns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>();
        this.groups = new ArrayList<ColumnGroup>();
    }

    public void add(TableColumn column) {
        columns.add(column);
    }

    public void add(ColumnGroup group) {
        groups.add(group);
    }

    /**
     * @param column
     *            TableColumn
     */
    public List<ColumnGroup> getColumnGroups(TableColumn column) {
        if (!contains(column)) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<ColumnGroup> result = new ArrayList<ColumnGroup>();
        result.add(this);
        if (columns.contains(column)) {
            return result;
        }
        for (ColumnGroup columnGroup : groups) {
            result.addAll(columnGroup.getColumnGroups(column));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean contains(TableColumn column) {
        if (columns.contains(column)) {
            return true;
        }
        for (ColumnGroup group : groups) {
            if (group.contains(column)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public TableCellRenderer getHeaderRenderer() {
        return renderer;
    }

    public void setHeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    public String getHeaderValue() {
        return text;
    }

    public Dimension getSize(JTable table) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = this.renderer;
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }
        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, getHeaderValue() == null || getHeaderValue().trim().isEmpty() ? " "
                : getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, -1);
        int height = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
        int width = 0;
        for (ColumnGroup columnGroup : groups) {
            width += columnGroup.getSize(table).width;
        }
        for (TableColumn tableColumn : columns) {
            width += tableColumn.getWidth();
            width += margin;
        }
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public void setColumnMargin(int margin) {
        this.margin = margin;
        for (ColumnGroup columnGroup : groups) {
            columnGroup.setColumnMargin(margin);
        }
    }

}
```

GroupableTableHeader.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GroupableTableHeader extends JTableHeader {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String uiClassID = "GroupableTableHeaderUI";

    protected List<ColumnGroup> columnGroups = new ArrayList<ColumnGroup>();

    public GroupableTableHeader(TableColumnModel model) {
        super(model);
        setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
        setReorderingAllowed(false);
        // setDefaultRenderer(new MultiLineHeaderRenderer());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUI() {
        setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void setReorderingAllowed(boolean b) {
        super.setReorderingAllowed(false);
    }

    public void addColumnGroup(ColumnGroup g) {
        columnGroups.add(g);
    }

    public List<ColumnGroup> getColumnGroups(TableColumn col) {
        for (ColumnGroup group : columnGroups) {
            List<ColumnGroup> groups = group.getColumnGroups(col);
            if (!groups.isEmpty()) {
                return groups;
            }
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public void setColumnMargin() {
        int columnMargin = getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();
        for (ColumnGroup group : columnGroups) {
            group.setColumnMargin(columnMargin);
        }
    }

}
```

GroupableTableHeaderUI.java

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class GroupableTableHeaderUI extends BasicTableHeaderUI {

    protected GroupableTableHeader getHeader() {
        return (GroupableTableHeader) header;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
        if (header.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        int column = 0;
        Dimension size = header.getSize();
        Rectangle cellRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        Map<ColumnGroup, Rectangle> groupSizeMap = new HashMap<ColumnGroup, Rectangle>();

        for (Enumeration<TableColumn> enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();) {
            cellRect.height = size.height;
            cellRect.y = 0;
            TableColumn aColumn = enumeration.nextElement();
            List<ColumnGroup> groups = getHeader().getColumnGroups(aColumn);
            int groupHeight = 0;
            for (ColumnGroup group : groups) {
                Rectangle groupRect = groupSizeMap.get(group);
                if (groupRect == null) {
                    groupRect = new Rectangle(cellRect);
                    Dimension d = group.getSize(header.getTable());
                    groupRect.width = d.width;
                    groupRect.height = d.height;
                    groupSizeMap.put(group, groupRect);
                }
                paintCell(g, groupRect, group);
                groupHeight += groupRect.height;
                cellRect.height = size.height - groupHeight;
                cellRect.y = groupHeight;
            }
            cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth();
            if (cellRect.intersects(clipBounds)) {
                paintCell(g, cellRect, column);
            }
            cellRect.x += cellRect.width;
            column++;
        }
    }

    private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, int columnIndex) {
        TableColumn aColumn = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex);
        TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {

            // original
            renderer = getHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

            // modified
            renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
                public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                    FilterHeader header = new FilterHeader( table, value, column);
                    return header;
                }

            };
        }
        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false, false,
                -1, columnIndex);

        c.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));

        rendererPane.paintComponent(g, c, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y, cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
    }

    private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, ColumnGroup cGroup) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = cGroup.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = getHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }

        Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(header.getTable(), cGroup.getHeaderValue(), false,
                false, -1, -1);
        rendererPane
                .paintComponent(g, component, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y, cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
    }

    private int getHeaderHeight() {
        int headerHeight = 0;
        TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
        for (int column = 0; column < columnModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            TableColumn aColumn = columnModel.getColumn(column);
            TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
            if (renderer == null) {
                renderer = getHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
            }

            Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false,
                    false, -1, column);
            int cHeight = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
            List<ColumnGroup> groups = getHeader().getColumnGroups(aColumn);
            for (ColumnGroup group : groups) {
                cHeight += group.getSize(header.getTable()).height;
            }
            headerHeight = Math.max(headerHeight, cHeight);
        }
        return headerHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        int width = 0;
        for (Enumeration<TableColumn> enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();) {
            TableColumn aColumn = enumeration.nextElement();
            width += aColumn.getPreferredWidth();
        }
        return createHeaderSize(width);
    }

    private Dimension createHeaderSize(int width) {
        TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
        width += columnModel.getColumnMargin() * columnModel.getColumnCount();
        if (width > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            width = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        return new Dimension(width, getHeaderHeight());
    }

}
```

GroupableHeaderExample.java

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

// original from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347647/how-to-combine-two-column-headers-in-jtable-in-swings
public class GroupableHeaderExample extends JFrame {

      GroupableHeaderExample() {
        super( "Groupable Header Example" );

        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dm.setDataVector(new Object[][]{
          {"1","a","b","c","d","e"},
          {"2","f","g","h","i","j"},
          {"3","k","l","m","n","o"},
          {"4","p","q","r","s","t"}
          },
        new Object[]{"SNo.","1","2","Native","2","3"});

        JTable table = new JTable( dm ) {
          protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
              return new GroupableTableHeader(columnModel);
          }
        };


        TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();
        ColumnGroup g_name = new ColumnGroup("Name");
        g_name.add(cm.getColumn(1));
        g_name.add(cm.getColumn(2));
        ColumnGroup g_lang = new ColumnGroup("Language");
        g_lang.add(cm.getColumn(3));
        ColumnGroup g_other = new ColumnGroup("Others");
        g_other.add(cm.getColumn(4));
        g_other.add(cm.getColumn(5));
        g_lang.add(g_other);

        GroupableTableHeader header = (GroupableTableHeader)table.getTableHeader();
        header.addColumnGroup(g_name);
        header.addColumnGroup(g_lang);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scroll );
        setSize( 400, 120 );   

        // allow sorting
        RowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(dm);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroupableHeaderExample frame = new GroupableHeaderExample();
        frame.setSize(1024,768);
        frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) {
      System.exit(0);
          }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by combining various sources.

One source was [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860204/multiple-editable-rows-in-jtable-header/26861494#26861494), but that solution put the filter only outside of the table.

Another source was the [open source version of a TableFilter on coderazzi](http://coderazzi.net/tablefilter/). That's very awesome, but also very heavy weight for my needs. And doesn't support grouped columns. So all in all what I needed was this piece of code:

```
JViewport headerViewport = new JViewport() {
    
    @Override
    public void setView(Component view) {
        if (view instanceof JTableHeader) {
            filterHeader.add(view, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            super.setView(filterHeader);
        }
    }
};

scroll.setColumnHeader(headerViewport);
```

and

```
private class TableFilterHeader extends JPanel {
    public TableFilterHeader(JTableHeader th) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new TableFilterRow(th.getTable()), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

A screenshot:

[image]

Interested ones can get the [full code from this gist](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/dcd349dbf6f976a7552a). What's missing is the filter itself, but that's just straightforward: Add a document listener and apply the filter.